# Saving ggplot from Shiny gives blank png file

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, png

I am trying to save a `ggplot2` object made in a `shiny` app. Basically this code allows `.xlsx` files to be uploaded and plots created after selecting from some options. I have then included a download button so that the user may download the plot they have created. I am using `downloadHandler()` and `grDevices::png()`. Pressing the button does cause a `.png` file to be downloaded, but when I open it, it is just a blank, white square. I am so close! Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
#initialize
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)


#example data
data(iris)

#make some factors
#easier to let ggplot2 control plotting (color, fill) based on type
data(mtcars)
uvals<-sapply(mtcars,function(x){length(unique(x))})
mtcars<-map_if(mtcars,uvals<4,as.factor) %>%
  as.data.frame()


#plotting theme for ggplot2
.theme<- theme(
  axis.line = element_line(colour = 'gray', size = .75),
  panel.background = element_blank(),
  plot.background = element_blank()
)


# UI for app
ui<-(pageWithSidebar(
  # title
  headerPanel("Select Options"),

  #input
  sidebarPanel
  (
    # Input: Select a file ----

    fileInput("file1", "Choose xlsx File",
              multiple = TRUE,
              accept = c(".xlsx")),


    # Horizontal line ----
    tags$hr(),


    #download button
     fluidPage(downloadButton('down')),

    # Input: Select what to display
    selectInput("dataset","Data:",
                choices =list(iris = "iris", mtcars = "mtcars",
                              uploaded_file = "inFile"), selected=NULL),
    selectInput("xaxis","X axis:", choices = NULL),
    selectInput("yaxis","Y axis:", choices = NULL),
    selectInput("fill","Fill:", choices = NULL),
    selectInput("group","Group:", choices = NULL),
    selectInput("plot.type","Plot Type:",
                list(boxplot = "boxplot", histogram = "histogram", density = "density", bar = "bar")
    ),
    checkboxInput("show.points", "show points", TRUE)
  ),

  # output
  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption")),
    #h3(htmlOutput("caption")),
    uiOutput("plot") # depends on input
  )
))


# shiny server side code for each call
server<-function(input, output, session){

  #update group and
  #variables based on the data
  observe({
    #browser()
    if(!exists(input$dataset)) return() #make sure upload exists
    var.opts<-colnames(get(input$dataset))
    updateSelectInput(session, "xaxis", choices = var.opts)
    updateSelectInput(session, "yaxis", choices = var.opts)
    updateSelectInput(session, "fill", choices = var.opts)
    updateSelectInput(session, "group", choices = var.opts)
  })

  output$caption<-renderText({
    switch(input$plot.type,
           "boxplot"    =   "Boxplot",
           "histogram" =    "Histogram",
           "density"    =   "Density plot",
           "bar"        =   "Bar graph")
  })


  output$plot <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("p")
  })

  #get data object
  get_data<-reactive({

    if(!exists(input$dataset)) return() # if no upload

    check<-function(x){is.null(x) || x==""}
    if(check(input$dataset)) return()

    obj<-list(data=get(input$dataset),
              yaxis=input$yaxis,
              xaxis=input$xaxis,
              fill=input$fill,
              group=input$group
    )

    #require all to be set to proceed
    if(any(sapply(obj,check))) return()
    #make sure choices had a chance to update
    check<-function(obj){
      !all(c(obj$yaxis,obj$xaxis, obj$fill,obj$group) %in% colnames(obj$data))
    }

    if(check(obj)) return()


    obj

  })

  #plotting function using ggplot2
  output$p <- renderPlot({

    plot.obj<-get_data()

    #conditions for plotting
    if(is.null(plot.obj)) return()

    #make sure variable and group have loaded
    if(plot.obj$yaxis == "" | plot.obj$xaxis =="" | plot.obj$fill ==""| plot.obj$group =="") return()

    #plot types
    plot.type<-switch(input$plot.type,
                      "boxplot"     = geom_boxplot(),
                      "histogram" = geom_histogram(alpha=0.5,position="identity"),
                      "density"     =   geom_density(alpha=.75),
                      "bar"         =   geom_bar(position="dodge")
    )


    if(input$plot.type=="boxplot")  {       #control for 1D or 2D graphs
      p<-ggplot(plot.obj$data,
                aes_string(
                  x         = plot.obj$xaxis,
                  y         = plot.obj$yaxis,
                  fill  = plot.obj$fill,# let type determine plotting
                  group = plot.obj$group
                )
      ) + plot.type

      if(input$show.points==TRUE)
      {
        p<-p+ geom_point(color='black',alpha=0.5, position = 'jitter')
      }

    } else {

      p<-ggplot(plot.obj$data,
                aes_string(
                  x         = plot.obj$xaxis,
                  fill  = plot.obj$fill,
                  group     = plot.obj$group
                  #color    = as.factor(plot.obj$group)
                )
      ) + plot.type
    }

    p<-p+labs(
      fill  = input$fill,
      x         = "",
      y         = input$yaxis
    )  +
      .theme
    print(p)
  })

  # set uploaded file
  upload_data<-reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    #could also store in a reactiveValues
    read_excel(inFile$datapath)
  })

  observeEvent(input$file1,{
    inFile<<-upload_data()
  })

  # downloadHandler contains 2 arguments as functions, namely filename, content
  output$down <- downloadHandler(
    filename =  function() {
      paste(input$dataset,"png" , sep=".")
    },
    # content is a function with argument file. content writes the plot to the device
    content = function(file) {
      png(file) # open the png device
      p # for GGPLOT
      dev.off()  # turn the device off

    } 
  )

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try explicitly printing `print(p)` in the saving script. (Or use `ggsave` instead...)

Comment: @Gregor thank you for the tips. `print(p)` gives the same result and I tried `ggsave(file, plot=p, device='png')`, but get the error `no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: I'd advise having all your code that builds the plot into a `reactive()` object (let's say `p`) and call up that object in `renderPlot()` instead of doing it all within `renderPlot()` Then, remove `png(file) # open the png device; p # for GGPLOT; dev.off()` and change it to `ggsave(file, p())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I responded as a comment, but I recognize it's a little hard to follow, so I'll post the full revised code to make it clearer.

I generally recommend to not do too much within `render*()` calls. Rather, set up the object you're looking to create in a separate `reactive()` object, and just refer to that in `renderPlot()`. In the code below, I moved all your code that creates the plot into a `reactive` object named `p`, and then I can refer to it in `ggsave()` for the downloading.

```
#initialize
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)


#example data
data(iris)

#make some factors
#easier to let ggplot2 control plotting (color, fill) based on type
data(mtcars)
uvals<-sapply(mtcars,function(x){length(unique(x))})
mtcars<-map_if(mtcars,uvals<4,as.factor) %>%
  as.data.frame()


#plotting theme for ggplot2
.theme<- theme(
  axis.line = element_line(colour = 'gray', size = .75),
  panel.background = element_blank(),
  plot.background = element_blank()
)


# UI for app
ui<-(pageWithSidebar(
  # title
  headerPanel("Select Options"),

  #input
  sidebarPanel
  (
    # Input: Select a file ----

    fileInput("file1", "Choose xlsx File",
              multiple = TRUE,
              accept = c(".xlsx")),


    # Horizontal line ----
    tags$hr(),


    #download button
    fluidPage(downloadButton('down')),

    # Input: Select what to display
    selectInput("dataset","Data:",
                choices =list(iris = "iris", mtcars = "mtcars",
                              uploaded_file = "inFile"), selected=NULL),
    selectInput("xaxis","X axis:", choices = NULL),
    selectInput("yaxis","Y axis:", choices = NULL),
    selectInput("fill","Fill:", choices = NULL),
    selectInput("group","Group:", choices = NULL),
    selectInput("plot.type","Plot Type:",
                list(boxplot = "boxplot", histogram = "histogram", density = "density", bar = "bar")
    ),
    checkboxInput("show.points", "show points", TRUE)
  ),

  # output
  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption")),
    #h3(htmlOutput("caption")),
    uiOutput("plot") # depends on input
  )
))


# shiny server side code for each call
server<-function(input, output, session){

  #update group and
  #variables based on the data
  observe({
    #browser()
    if(!exists(input$dataset)) return() #make sure upload exists
    var.opts<-colnames(get(input$dataset))
    updateSelectInput(session, "xaxis", choices = var.opts)
    updateSelectInput(session, "yaxis", choices = var.opts)
    updateSelectInput(session, "fill", choices = var.opts)
    updateSelectInput(session, "group", choices = var.opts)
  })

  output$caption<-renderText({
    switch(input$plot.type,
           "boxplot"    =   "Boxplot",
           "histogram" =    "Histogram",
           "density"    =   "Density plot",
           "bar"        =   "Bar graph")
  })


  output$plot <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("p")
  })

  #get data object
  get_data<-reactive({

    if(!exists(input$dataset)) return() # if no upload

    check<-function(x){is.null(x) || x==""}
    if(check(input$dataset)) return()

    obj<-list(data=get(input$dataset),
              yaxis=input$yaxis,
              xaxis=input$xaxis,
              fill=input$fill,
              group=input$group
    )

    #require all to be set to proceed
    if(any(sapply(obj,check))) return()
    #make sure choices had a chance to update
    check<-function(obj){
      !all(c(obj$yaxis,obj$xaxis, obj$fill,obj$group) %in% colnames(obj$data))
    }

    if(check(obj)) return()


    obj

  })

  p <- reactive({
    plot.obj<-get_data()

    #conditions for plotting
    if(is.null(plot.obj)) return()

    #make sure variable and group have loaded
    if(plot.obj$yaxis == "" | plot.obj$xaxis =="" | plot.obj$fill ==""| plot.obj$group =="") return()

    #plot types
    plot.type<-switch(input$plot.type,
                      "boxplot"     = geom_boxplot(),
                      "histogram" = geom_histogram(alpha=0.5,position="identity"),
                      "density"     =   geom_density(alpha=.75),
                      "bar"         =   geom_bar(position="dodge")
    )


    if(input$plot.type=="boxplot")  {       #control for 1D or 2D graphs
      p<-ggplot(plot.obj$data,
                aes_string(
                  x         = plot.obj$xaxis,
                  y         = plot.obj$yaxis,
                  fill  = plot.obj$fill,# let type determine plotting
                  group = plot.obj$group
                )
      ) + plot.type

      if(input$show.points==TRUE)
      {
        p<-p+ geom_point(color='black',alpha=0.5, position = 'jitter')
      }

    } else {

      p<-ggplot(plot.obj$data,
                aes_string(
                  x         = plot.obj$xaxis,
                  fill  = plot.obj$fill,
                  group     = plot.obj$group
                  #color    = as.factor(plot.obj$group)
                )
      ) + plot.type
    }

    p<-p+labs(
      fill  = input$fill,
      x         = "",
      y         = input$yaxis
    )  +
      .theme
    print(p)
  })

  #plotting function using ggplot2
  output$p <- renderPlot({
    p()
  })

  # set uploaded file
  upload_data<-reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    #could also store in a reactiveValues
    read_excel(inFile$datapath)
  })

  observeEvent(input$file1,{
    inFile<<-upload_data()
  })

  # downloadHandler contains 2 arguments as functions, namely filename, content
  output$down <- downloadHandler(
    filename =  function() {
      paste(input$dataset,"png" , sep=".")
    },
    # content is a function with argument file. content writes the plot to the device
    content = function(file) {
      ggsave(file, p())
    } 
  )

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Excellent. answer.  Helped me greatly.